# searching keys in dictionary swift

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, swift3

I want to search for the key **id** in the dictionary. I have a dictionary like this:

```
var tableData:[String:Any] = ["id":["path":"","type":"","parameters":[]]]
```

Table data has 307 items, and all **id**'s unique. I want to search in dictionary key **id**, like when I write **"get"** , it need the show all the search results with **"get"** in table view.

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    let searchString = searchController.searchBar.text

    if let entry = tableData.keys.first(where: { $0.lowercased().contains(searchString) }) {
        print(entry)
    } else {
        print("no match")
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}


func didChangeSearchText(searchText: String) {

    if let entry = tableData.keys.first(where: { $0.lowercased().contains(searchText) }) {
        print(entry)
    } else {
        print("no match")
    }
    // Reload the tableview.
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

When I try to search a word it prints **"no match"**, in the debug, unable to read data writes for the value of the **entry**. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You want to search with ids?

Comment: Give a proper example of what you want

Comment: `entry` is an array?

Comment: tableData.keys.first is "id" , what do you want to searching?

Comment: I want to search in "id". Every id is unique. like                                        `[["a"::["path":"","type":"","parameters":[]]],["b"::["path":"","type":"","parameters":[]]],["c"::["path":"","type":"","parameters":[]]]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact your keys have to be unique and as in your case `id` is a top level key you don't have to perform filtering in order to access its value. Simply use `tableData[searchText]` to grab its value.

If you don't know the `id` value and you want to loop through all the keys you can do so like

```
for key in tableData.keys {
   print(key)
   let value = tableData[key]
   // or do whatever else you want with your key value
}
```

As per what you already have in place you need to do the following

```
var tableData:[String:Any] = ["hello world":["path":"fgh","type":"dfghgfh","parameters":[]], "something else":["path":"sdfsdfsdf","type":"dfghfghfg","parameters":[]]]

if let entry = tableData.keys.first(where: { $0.lowercased().contains("hello") }) {
    print(entry)
    // prints 'hello world'
} else {
    print("no match")
}
```

Or you can simply get a new filtered array from your data source like

```
let result = tableData.filter { (key, value) in
    key.lowercased().contains("else") // your search text replaces 'else'
}
/*
 * result would be an array with the objects based on your id search 
 * so you'll not only have the keys but the entire object as well
 */
print("Found \(result.count) matches")
```

Answer (score 1):

To access an element in a Dictionary with a key, use the following code.

```
if let entry = tableData[searchText] {
   print(entry)
}
```

For further information, have a look at:

[how can i get key's value from dictionary in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25741114/how-can-i-get-keys-value-from-dictionary-in-swift)

Comment: I have unique 307 id. And I don't know all names, I want to search in it, like when I write **get** , it need the show all the search results with **get**  in table view.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `first(where:)` directly on `tableData`, like this:

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    guard let searchString = searchController.searchBar.text else { return }

    if let (id, entry) = tableData.first(where: { (key, value) -> Bool in key.lowercased().contains(searchString) }) {
        print(entry)
    } else {
        print("no match")
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}


func didChangeSearchText(searchText: String) {

    if let (id, entry) = tableData.first(where: { (key, value) -> Bool in key.lowercased().contains(searchText) }) {
        print(entry)
    } else {
        print("no match")
    }
    // Reload the tableview.
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```